# How does padding-margin combination work on navbar-header class in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Recently I've noted that `.navbar-header` has `-15px` margin on left and right for viewport width < 768px. Probably to compensate the `15px` padding of `container`. So far so good. But for viewport width greater than 768px `.navbar-header` has no margins. The `.navbar-brand` is given the `15px left margin` for viewport width greater than `768px`.

- What is the reason of changing margins from `.navbar-header` to `.navbar-brand`?

My guess is that since for width greater than 768 the toggle menu button is invisible and the negative margin on `.navbar-header` would would pull the `navbar` list elements `15px` removing the guttur between the logo and navigation items. So they just took away margin-right when the menu toggle button is not there.

Comment: so what exactly is your question?

Comment: @RachelS My question is What is the reason of changing margins from `.navbar-header` to `.navbar-brand` when viewport width changes from below to 768 px to higher than 768px?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 <div class="drawer-overlay">

        Your main nav content goes here.
 </div>
```

after that apply script

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

    $('.drawer').drawer({

    nav: 'drawer-nav',

    navList:     'drawer-nav-list',

    overlay:     'drawer-overlay',

    toggle:      'drawer-toggle',

    openClass:   'drawer-open',

    closeClass:  'drawer-close',

    desktopEvent: 'mouseover', // or click

    speed: 200,

    width: 280,

    });

    });

    </script>
```